# ASP.NET web site assembly binding redirection stopped working on my machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, assembly-binding-redirect

I have found a bunch of question about this error. Tried mostly everything, but nothings helps.

I'm creating new web project in my visual studio 2013 update 3 and its still giving me error.

Same type of issue is when I'm updating OWIN from 2.1.0 to 3.0.0 .

This is my Web.config file generated by wizard.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20140829051636.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20140829051636;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I got same problem on 3 different projects.
My opinion is that NET just ignores my redirects.

Please help me.

Comment: I have had this when a project in the same solution has a nuget package installed that has a higher version than the one referenced in my web app.  Might be worth checking all your packages are in sync and that no project is referencing a version of a package that is a higher version that the newVersion specified in the binding redirect.

Comment: @Ben this is an initial project generated by ASP.NET web wizard with individual authentication. Double checked references, everything is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved this.

My development path name was '#dev'.
Changed '#dev' to 'dev' and it worked.

I think # is a special character for .NET assembly binding redirection system.